# how to write gray (1-channel) image with opencv for python

Tags: python, opencv

I just would like to know if it's possible to save gray 1 channel images with opencv starting from rgb images.

```
import cv2
bgr_img = cv2.imread('anyrgbimage.jpg')
print(bgr_img.shape) #(x,y,3)
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imwrite('hopefully_gray_image.jpg',gray_img)
#cv2.imwrite('hopefully_gray_image.jpg',gray_img,[int(cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)])
buh_img = cv2.imread('hopefully_gray_image.jpg')
print(buh_img.shape) #(x,y,3)
```

i know i can add some parameters inside cv2.imwrite, but i can't figure out what.

Comment: with png is the same. Anyway i want to know the parameters to write it 1-channel not the way to read it back grayscale.

Comment: bmp images have a grayscale formats

Comment: @Miki Ah, my mistake. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @miki: your second answer was richer, and i understood. It works. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Yes, it is. Let me elaborate on [@Miki's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54639394/how-to-write-gray-1-channel-image-with-opencv-for-python/54639919#comment96070719_54639394) to your answer. If you take a look at the documentation of [`imread(filename[, flags])`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56), you will see that the default flag is `cv2.IMREAD_COLOR`, i.e., OpenCV will load the image with 3 channels, by default (even if it has 1 or 4 channels). If you want to use the same `imread(...)` to load both three- and single-channel images, you should use the flag `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED`. In practice, how does that work?

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = (np.random.random((300, 300, 3)) * 255.).astype(np.uint8)
# let's save 4 images (color/gray, png/jpg)
cv2.imwrite('img-png-color.png', img)          # output size: 270KB
cv2.imwrite('img-png-gray.png', img[:, :, 1])  # output size: 90KB
cv2.imwrite('img-jpg-color.jpg', img)          # output size: 109KB
cv2.imwrite('img-jpg-gray.jpg', img[:, :, 1])  # output size: 93KB
```

There are two things to note:

- The color PNG image file is 3x larger than the gray PNG image;
- JPEG is working well, ty :)

Now, if you read ANY of these images using the default flag, they will be loaded with a shape of (300, 300, 3). However, if you proceed as @Miki told you:

```py
cv2.imread('img-png-color.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED).shape  # (300, 300, 3)
cv2.imread('img-png-gray.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED).shape   # (300, 300)
cv2.imread('img-jpg-color.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED).shape  # (300, 300, 3)
cv2.imread('img-jpg-gray.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED).shape   # (300, 300)
```

Therefore, in fact, the gray images were "saved" as single-channel.

Comment: Nice... I'm saving this for the next thousand duplicates... ;)

Comment: @Miki I often see myself using one of your answers for duplicates as well =]

Comment: i read the gray images with keras ImageDatagenerator flow_from_directory so arguing on how to read with cv2 it's useless. anyway i understood the principle as i've already said .

Comment: @arj ? What was that? Your question has nothing to do with Keras and you tagged it with OpenCV. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: what does this have to do with *write*?

Comment: @KansaiRobot this answer says not only how to write, but how to read it properly; otherwise you may think you wrote it in the wrong way, but that was not problem in OP's case