# Can't convert black&white image to grayscale in Opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new to opencv so don't mind me!

I want to convert an image which is a black and white image to gray scale image and save it by using `cv2.imwrite()`. The problem is that after I saved it to my local drive and read it back it returned as a 3 channels image. What is the problem here?
Here is my code

```py
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("path/to/image/image01.jpg")
print(image.shape) # return (128, 128, 3)

gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print(gray_image.shape) # return (128, 128)
cv2.imwrite("path/to/dir/gray01.jpg", gray_image)

new_gray_img = cv2.imread("path/to/dir/gray01.jpg")
print(new_gray_img.shape) # return (128, 128, 3)
```

[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7U83.jpg) i want to convert to gray.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54639394/how-to-write-gray-1-channel-image-with-opencv-for-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**cv2.imread** loads images with 3 channels by default

You can replace the last two lines of code using:

```
new_gray_img = cv2.imread("path/to/dir/gray01.jpg",cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
print(new_gray_img.shape)
```

Another method is to load image with **scipy**:

```
from scipy.ndimage import imread
new_gray_image=imread("path/to/dir/gray01.jpg")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to read the image directly in grayscale
`cv2.imread("path/to/dir/gray01.jpg", 0)`

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("path/to/image/image01.jpg")
print(image.shape) # return (128, 128, 3)

gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print(gray_image.shape) # return (128, 128)
cv2.imwrite("path/to/dir/gray01.jpg", gray_image)

# here is the change
new_gray_img = cv2.imread("path/to/dir/gray01.jpg", 0)
print(new_gray_img.shape) # return (128, 128)
```

Comment: Please don't use manifest constants like the zero at the end of your `imread()`. They are ugly, their purpose/meaning is unclear, they risk breaking with future releases and are a maintenance nightmare. There is a perfectly good parameter defined for you... `cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`. Thank you.